# Как в словаре обратиться от значение к ключу

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая умеет шифровать и расшифровывать шифр подстановки. Программа принимает на вход две строки одинаковой длины, на первой строке записаны символы исходного алфавита, на второй строке — символы конечного алфавита, после чего идёт строка, которую нужно зашифровать переданным ключом, и ещё одна строка, которую нужно расшифровать.
Пусть, например, на вход программе передано:

```
abcd
*d%#
abacabadaba
#*%*d*%
```

Это значит, что символ **a** исходного сообщения заменяется на символ * в шифре, **b** заменяется на **d**, **c** — на **%** и d — на **#**.
Нужно зашифровать строку abacabadaba и расшифровать строку #*%*d*% с помощью этого шифра. Получаем следующие строки, которые и передаём на вывод программы:

```
*d*%*d*#*d*
dacabac
```

```
for k, v in s1.items():
    m1 = dict((zip(k, v)))
n = input()
n1 = input()
for i in n:
    if i in m1.keys():
        i = m1.get(i)
        print(i, end='')
for j in n1:
    if j in m1.values():
        for j1 in m1.keys():
            j = j1
            print(j)
```

Главная проблема в том что по ключу к значению я могу обратиться, и у меня получилось через метод **get()** зашифровать, а вот от значения к ключу я обратиться не могу. Возможно ли поменять ключи, и значения местами или я иду в не ту сторону, и надо по другому зашифровывать, и расшифровывать?

Comment: obratno =  {y: x for x, y in original.items()}

Comment: ахахах, как я раньше не додумался, огромное спасибо Интик

Comment: Не забудте, что если у вас будут одинаковые значения, то вы получите ключ последнего